# Online counterpoint materials

Tags: composition, counterpoint

For a long time I've wanted to teach myself counterpoint, but haven't been able to find any materials online. Are there any hidden tutorials anyone knows of, or good books written in English in the public domain online? Any kind of counterpoint is fine. I just want to start learning.

Comment: Don't forget that your local library is full of books that you can check out for free! Libraries nowaday are modernized. At my library I am able to search for music books online and then reserve those books for pickup.

Answer (score 4):

[A Practical Approach to Sixteenth-Century Counterpoint](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0881338524) - this is a great resource. Then, work to this one: [A Practical Approach to Eighteenth-Century Counterpoint](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0881338532). I've used both of these in my studies and highly recommend them!

Answer (score 3):

Well, there's always ["the" book on counterpoint](http://imslp.org/wiki/Gradus_ad_Parnassum_%28Fux,_Johann_Joseph%29).  There may be a translation online somewhere; that said, [this one](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0393002772) is pretty inexpensive, just not online.

Answer (score 3):

This is a very late answer, but in case anyone comes across this question in the near future, there's a terrific recent resource at [Open Music Theory](http://openmusictheory.com/contents.html). It's a web-based music theory textbook that covers several topics in the undergraduate curriculum. The "Strict two-voice composition (strict counterpoint)" section would be a great resource for online counterpoint study.

Answer (score 1):

I came across this page a while ago on google. The applet only works on windows, but I found it fun and informative.

http://homepage.eircom.net/~gerfmcc/SpeciesOne.html